# ssh to vagrant servers not posible when defining several servers in one vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

Does anyone know if there are any problems regarding ssh access to servers when several servers are defined in the vagrant file ?

Here is the content of my vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

 Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
 config.ssh.insert_key = false
 config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
 vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
 end


# Application server 1.
config.vm.define "app1" do |app|
app.vm.hostname = "orc-app1.dev"
app.vm.box = "centos7"
app.vm.network :public_network, ip: "192.168.60.4"
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
end

# Application server 2.
config.vm.define "app2" do |app|
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
app.vm.hostname = "orc-app2.dev"
app.vm.box = "centos7"
app.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.5"
end

# Database server.
config.vm.define "db" do |db|
config.ssh.forward_agent = true
db.vm.hostname = "orc-db.dev"
db.vm.box = "centos7"
db.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.60.6"
end
end
```

Vagrant ssh app1 works just fine, but if I try to access the server with ssh like ssh vagrant@192.168.60.6 it is not able to connect

The strange part is that I have to trouble to access it with "normal" ssh if i define each of the servers in seperate vagrant files.

I need normal ssh access cause I am trying to test my ansible playbooks before I go "live" on my cloud servers.

Are there any settings in the vagrant file I am missing? Why does this work if I have seperate vagrant files for each server ?

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from the forwarded ports. Try adding something like : `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2222`, with a different host number for each server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect via ssh to one of your multiple virtual machine, you should use the hostname, you have defined.

For example, to connect to your "db" machine, use :

```
ssh vagrant@orc-db.dev -p 22
```

You also can connect to your machine using :

```
vagrant ssh db
```

More information are available on http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html.